# How to test method which using file creation time

Tags: java, file, date, testing, time

I created simple method with return creation date of file to millis

```
public Long getFileCreationDate(File file) {
    try {
        return Files.readAttributes(file.toPath(), BasicFileAttributes.class).creationTime().toMillis();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return 0L;
    }
}
```

And now i'm trying to write some working test. I think i should use temporaryFolder, create some file and... and whats should be next? How can i impose creation time?

Comment: Congratulations! Now you know why it is hard to unit-test procedual code. --- May I ask why you want to test this code? From what I see, it is simple enough and most of the business logic is done by `Files.readAttributes(...)`, which we should not need to test.

Comment: Exactly. Don't test EVERYTHING. Test things that actually make sense. Another detail: if you're using `Long` as return type, you should `return null;` to indicate that no proper value could be found. Also, steer clear from AutoBoxing. If you used `long` instead, you should define and use constants to indicate invalid states/results. Returning `0` is smelly code.

Comment: i'm new in unit tests so i'm trying to test every method :d thx@JayC667 for that tip

Comment: @Lulex97 If you have a hammer... everything looks like a nail. Use the right tool for the right job. And sometimes we have to admit that the job is not worth doing. "Testing everything" is not the point. Test what matters.

Comment: If you want to take *unit test* literally, you should not have the `Files` class be part of what you test. Instead you should provide a stub for it so you control yourself what it returns to the method under test calling it.